# How can I keep a constant MySQL connection alive in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm currently developing Discord Bot, for data storing I'm using MySQL, but after some hours de connection dies. I was wondering if someone has a clue on how to do this. This the way I currently connect:

```
// Initalise Variables
var config;
var mysql, conn;
var fs;

try {
    // External Packages
    fs = require('fs');
    config = require('./config.json');
    mysql = require('mysql');

    // Connection Setup
    conn = mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.mysql.host,
        user: config.mysql.user,
        password: config.mysql.password,
        database: config.mysql.database
    });
    conn.connect();
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a MySQL connection pool while working with NodeJS and Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102364/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-connection-pool-while-working-with-nodejs-and-express)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to install forever and start the service again. Forever is a simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given script runs continuously. Once you install forever and run the node js file then it will keeps the file alive continuously. Using npm you can install forever

```
npm install forever -g
```

Then just restart the js file

Ex:

```
forever start app.js
```

Hope now the js serves continously without breaking the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the timeout setting else if would default to 10000ms or 10 seconds.

```
try {
    // External Packages
    fs = require('fs');
    config = require('./config.json');
    mysql = require('mysql');

    // Connection Setup
    conn = mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.mysql.host,
        user: config.mysql.user,
        password: config.mysql.password,
        database: config.mysql.database,
        connectTimeout: config.mysql.timeout //1000000 some large number 
    });
    conn.connect();
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

You should probably use a connection pool instead of a single DB connection (this doesn't seem to have always keep alive type of setting, and you would have to give a large timeout like above)

```
    try {
        // External Packages
        fs = require('fs');
        config = require('./config.json');
        mysql = require('mysql');

        // Connection Setup
        conn = mysql.createConnection({
            host: config.mysql.host,
            user: config.mysql.user,
            password: config.mysql.password,
            database: config.mysql.database,
            connectionLimit: 10,
            queueLimit: 20
        });
var pool = mysql.createPool(config);

var queryDB = function(qry, cb) {
    pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) {
        if(error) {
            cb(error, null);
        }
        else {
            connection.query(qry, function (e, rows) {
                connection.destroy();
                cb(e, rows);
            });
        }
    });
```