# Store MySql query output in a variable (Node js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to make an sql query and want to store the output in a variable.
I can't find any solution to make that work, can anyone help me please?

```
const { createPool } = require("mysql")

const pool = createPool({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"ticketsystem",
    connectionLimit:10
})

const h = pool.query("select * from tblusers;", (err, res) => {
    return res
})

console.log(h)
```

Comment: You can ref to the solution in the link this[How do I create a MySQL connection pool while working with NodeJS and Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102364/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-connection-pool-while-working-with-nodejs-and-express)

Comment: is that post not just how to store the connection pool in variable isn't it?

Comment: You need call getConnection to check your server is exists or not.

Comment: the db is working. when i console.log() the res before the return, i get the right output. The problem is, that i cant store it in h.

Comment: you can console.log(res) before return, or you can use localstorage to save them

Comment: yes, i can console.log(res) before returning. I also get the expected result. I just can't use the output then. 
and it has to have a solution to save the output in a variable without using localstorage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is related to the asynchronous nature of the JavaScript execution: the code located in the `pool.query`'s callback function runs after the assignation of the `h` variable and after the `console.log`.

You have 2 options:

1. You can place your entire follow up code inside the callback function:

```
pool.query("select * from tblusers;", (err, res) => {
  const h = res
  // do whatever comes next here...
})
```

2. Promisify the result of the callback function and await its resolution before moving on

```
const h = await new Promise((resolve) => {
  pool.query("select * from tblusers;", (err, res) => {
    resolve(res)
  })
})

console.log(h)
// do whatever comes next here...
```

Note that if you are not using one of the latest versions of node (supporting top level await), you will have to place everything in an IIFE function:

```
(async () => {
  const pool = createPool({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"ticketsystem",
    connectionLimit:10
  })

  const h = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    pool.query("select * from tblusers;", (err, res) => {
      resolve(res)
    })
  })

  console.log(h)
  // do whatever comes next here...
})()
```